# Python3 BigQuery - Strange timestamp problem

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have a strange problem: when I execute a query like `... WHERE DATE(timestamp) BETWEEN DATE('{export_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} 00:00:00') and DATE('{export_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} 23:59:59') ...`

in the results of the query I find some data inherent to the current day from the 00:00 AM to 00:50 AM, so it gives me some data about the current day.

I use Python3 with `google-cloud-bigquery`  and `datetime` libraries from dockerized microservice.
Is it maybe a timezone problem?

P.S: export_date = datetime.now()

Comment: This probably isn't enough information. If it is a timezone problem, you need to know the difference in the time zones. Do you have access to the docker container's environment so you could check the current date and time on it? And the same question applies to the saved data: what timezone is it saved from? Is it local timestamp, or does it have the timezone information?

Comment: It's possible.  Is the data stored in GMT?

Comment: I check the timezone inside the pod, is Europe/Rome. The data stored on BigQuery is in UTC.  Timezone probem I guess, right?

Comment: Edit: I've tried to set UTC timezone in container and now I retrieve data from 2022-02-22 to 2022-02-23

Comment: @EcceRobot, is that the intended result now? Or are you saying it's off by a day?

Comment: @Arseny nope, it's off by day. I've to use this form in select statement: ```  where date(timestamp) = DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) ``` but still not works

Comment: @EcceRobot, maybe that's b/c the time was off when the date was saved. Maybe try interval 1 hour, in whatever direction is needed, instead?

Comment: @EcceRobot, also, what does the raw timestamp look like? Like, if you do `select timestamp limit 1`?

Comment: @Arseny I can't use bidirectional interval because I've to export data inherent to 1 day ago. The row timestamp is this: 2022-02-24 00:00:11 UTC

Comment: @EcceRobot, not sure why you can't use a 1-hour interval (I suppose you'd need TIMESTAMP_ADD for that). By the whatever direction I meant you'd just have to decide which direction it needs to be adjusted. But it's probably not relevant now, since your timestamp is in UTC. If you just do `select CURRENT_DATE()`, do you get the time you expect? What about `CURRENT_DATETIME()` and `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()`?

Comment: @EcceRobot, another thought - what do you get by `select DATE(TIMESTAMP '2022-02-23 23:00:00 UTC')`? I'm just curious if the `DATE` call converts the timestamp to a local date

Comment: @Arseny yes, give me 2022-02-24 22:30:45.147258 UTC. Is correct but when i execute the query the results include 2022-02-22 ineherent data. I've tried to use BETWEEN statement but still not works

Comment: @Arseny executing select DATE(TIMESTAMP '2022-02-23 23:00:00 UTC') return me 2022-02-23, correct right?

Comment: @EcceRobot, yes, that's correct. I realized now BigQuery always uses UTC as the default timezone. Maybe it's something in Python? How do you pass the date to the script? Can you show any Python code in the original question?

Comment: @Arseny yes, sure: WHERE DATE(timestamp) BETWEEN DATE('{export_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} 00:00:00') and DATE('{export_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')} 23:59:59'). I use datetime module and "timestamp" is the name of the field not BQ keyword

Comment: @Arseny export_date = datetime.now()

Comment: @EcceRobot, I meant you should update your original question with this Python code so people could see the whole picture without reading our comments. It's generally a good practice to give more detail and some examples of input and output